# Confusion about extending the definition of stochastic integral to continuous local martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, self-learning, stochastic-analysis

In Jean-François Le Gall's *Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus*, the author defines the stochastic integral for a continuous local martingale $M$ in Chapter 5, which is defined as $H \cdot M$ a continuous local martingale with initial value $0$, satisfying
$$
\langle H \cdot M, N \rangle = H \cdot \langle M, N\rangle
$$

for any continuous local martingale. (here $H \in L_{loc}^2 (M)$)

I am a bit confused about the construction of $H \cdot M$.

The author first defines a sequence of stopping times $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ that reduce $M$ and defines

$$
(H \cdot M)^{T_n} = H \cdot M^{T_n}
$$

which makes sense by the construction of stochastic integral in continuous martingale case (included below as Theorem 5.4) and he also claims since $(H \cdot M)_t = \lim (H\cdot M^{T_n})_t$, the constructed $H\cdot M$ is continuous and adapted.

**Questions:**

- I fail to see why the limit is well-defined, while the author gives a justification according to the stopping time property in Theorem 5.4, we have $H\cdot M^{T_n}=(H\cdot M^{T_m})^{T_n}, \forall m >n$.
- Also, I have read the relevant section in *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Yor & Revuz, it seems that the authors claim that specifying $H\cdot M$'s values on $[0, T_n]$ is sufficient, I wonder why that is true (I understand the stopping time property ensures the definitions are consistent on intervals $[0, T_n]$)

**Notations:**

- $L^2(M)$: The set of progressive processes $H$ such that $E\left[\int_0^\infty H_s^2 d\langle M, M \rangle_s\right]<\infty$
- $L^2_{loc}(M)$: The set of progressive processes $H$ such that $\int_0^t H_s^2 d\langle M, M \rangle_s<\infty, \forall t \geq 0$ almost surely
- $\mathbb{H}^2$: the space of all continuous martingales bounded in $L^2$ ($\sup_{t\geq 0} E[X_t^2] < \infty$)
- $T_n$: in the context above, $T_n$ is defined as $\inf\{t\geq 0: \int_0^t (1+H_s^2)d \langle M, M \rangle_s\geq n\}$

> **Theorem 5.4** Let $M \in \mathbb{H}^2$. For every elementary process $H$ of the form
> $$ H_s(\omega) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} H_{(i)} (\omega) \mathbf{1}_{(t_i,
>  t_{i+1}]}(s) $$
>
> the formula
>
> $$ (H\cdot M)_t = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} H_{(i)}(M_{t_{i+1} \land t} -
>  M_{t_i \land t}) $$
>
> defines a process $H\cdot M\in \mathbb{H}^2$. The mapping $H\mapsto
>  H\cdot M$ extends to an isometry from $L^2(M)$ to $\mathbb{H}^2$.
> Furthermore, $H\cdot M$ is the unique martingale in $\mathbb{H}^2$
> that satisfies  $\forall H \in L^2 (M)$
>
> $$ \langle H \cdot M, N \rangle = H \cdot \langle M, N\rangle $$
>
> In addition, if $T$ is a stopping time, we have $$
>  (\mathbf{1}_{[0,T]}H) \cdot M = (H\cdot M)^T = H \cdot M^T $$